# How to encrypt columns in a database (i.e. email, f, m, l, etc.) and be able to easily change encryption key

Tags: c#, sql-server, encryption

I have several fields in a database table I would like to encrypt, but I would like to do it in a way that would allow me to easily change the encryption key every n months for security reasons.  My initial thought was to store the IV with the row so I could use that to decrypt each entry where the key for the encryption would be stored elsewhere, in code or a config file.

This seems like it will be a nightmare every n months when I needed to change the key, as I would have to have some job run that would need to change the IV for every row along with decrypting/encrypting again all of the necessary columns to the new key.  It just seems like this approach could also bog the system down while trying to decrypt and encrypt again.  I have not seen alot of articles describing practical approaches to this problem, just mentionings that the key should be changed periodically.

I am new to the encryption game. I am using AES-256 encryption.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the sensitivity of the data you are trying to secure. If the data is very sensitive to your usecase then the complexity of the encryption method will scale accordingly. On the contrary you can use simpler techniques to secure "less-sesnsitive" data. Either way storing the IV in the row isnt the best thing to do because in case your transactions are vulnerable to SQL Injections, you risk leakage of your entire data.

Coming to your question, If you have highly sensitive data then you might need to use techniques like AES 256 which will be heavy in the case of key migration and other modifications. Or, you can use simple methods like a one-time-pad with a randomly generated key and store the key in a secure keystores. You can replace the key every n months and will have to decrypt/encrypt again. The only advantage you will have in this case is that OTP decryption/encryption is a way lighter process than AES decryption/encryption.

Note: There might be a more elegant way to do this. Try posting your question on https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks.  I will add to the security section.